# Unable to create a double variable in UI Path studio

Tags: uipath

I am unable to search for a double type variable in UI path studio ...[image]

[image]

Comment: What means search for a double? I cannot see a double variable in the picture.

Comment: I need to create a double variable type but there is no such option in the variable type dropdown.I tried to search here as well in the browse types option.Added the image in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scroll down a bit. There are plenty of `Double` types for sure.

What you are looking for is the `System.Double` type.

[image]

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thank you so much. I had to type System Double

Answer (score 0):

My best practice from my experience is when you search for Variable type start with System. Hence .NET default variable will be used and it ensures compatibilities.